# SQL - Managed Table vs External Table

Tags: sql, big-data, business-intelligence, hadoop, hive

Trago uma questão de SQL menos técnica.

Eu uso a ferramenta Hive, do Hadoop, para manipular os dados com SQL. E gostaria de saber uma situação real em que devo aplicar uma *managed table* e uma *external table*. Você poderia me dar algum exemplo?

A diferença técnica basicamente é quando vamos apagar a tabela. Sendo ela uma *managed table*, quando eu der o comando `DROP TABLE table_name`, a tabela, os dados e os metadados serão apagados. Já a
*external table*, ao dar este comando apenas a tabela e os metadados serão deletados, os dados da tabela permaneceram armazenados no diretório correspondente.

Valeu pessoal.

Comment: Não conheço o Hadoop mas apesar dos dados permaneceremm armazenados eles continuam acessíveis?

Comment: Prevalecem acessíveis, mas não como tabela.